# Invalid ViewState exceptions: exploit with Sitefinity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, exploit, sitefinity

We've been getting spammed with these exceptions in the logs about invalid ViewState from IP addresses that don't make sense (Arizona, Czechia Europe, etc. meanwhile we're 100% Canadian). Not sure if this is an attempt at some exploit but I'm hoping someone here has an idea of what might be going on.

We keep putting IP blocks on the source of them but then the IP just changes to a new one in a different part of the world.

If you look in the exception you'll see that the **Requested URL** makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Here is the exception (website name changed for obvious reasons):

```
Type : System.Web.UI.ViewStateException, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Message : Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 4.53.111.73
    Port: 1059
    Referer: 
    Path: /
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
    ViewState: /wEdAHyj1dqk3IwJYnQEm9AMQxcwD2H56SzRu5QEnJoT//YK1IMUd0v3 wt89MpXfh3p1l8s Df0XLc4FoTMaD1SoQzwrVEc4z4uoyrrXFfPjtexfCwgrPdQlzgOUCJcBYH2ANO0WTtC3H4mX PzpnDiKQxJEXNpIb0HeVgzGnSZ1ybEAqbF7kHkym1oiXl8Pm5w n7hn1UljxUxLa8 cChLY02y6Wizqk/p2m GKubN4 HlxvpOSBDGghv5Elsmov4r/r9Lrj/NQJzNO2TK5asJ/XokCyYicy 8W0NMmzmmpCa9eXzHntVPyiu5dUrV/Y7ZjZWy0gNdNZs67dLsK8/mR/fQEgmn4kYCpuCPR1H4t/Yw9g9s6ZW tvWZKkz5ydtldeaVduo WhCkKrH1AfLQIXeX1sq9WWkfxCtmfqL2Y4621d1ZRZd0nstpykR5Zxy5CrhFAEBRvYuDgVZiVhFEJVPNI/CX9qJzwjDPQjkfcr/bA6fjCCeBRNR92DhwF6qr Jg3qTcVskwubvOiIgZb7zSl0Qdql IrNjDCDz552eIUub3Y/9SLLGQSdweaNtB7BgnCR1J6EKCU33ZgLWmv wvRobejwdJFQZaztBnkjMzxXW/nUEjhJ5V8nYDfrzGVDPWybkKVvKOuWk5QtpHYDIeIxYBzauOeip0IpaaHzkoyOKy5PcLWsCkjLI93poyghoBRGtSIC3GnJBNBVkhTgHG5cAIVsnM6hynp AGu cU1Yd8NmUOmizgjCW98LZcnY05fIvYrDCMEtSheJkShipjZD1tSWocShqs5fqWz Ri7wP31bwEjopI DoMAujoNropdhvoZbGDVQON8riiDFFPqw8...
Source : 
Help link : 
RemoteAddress : 4.53.111.73
RemotePort : 1059
UserAgent : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
PersistedState : /wEdAHyj1dqk3IwJYnQEm9AMQxcwD2H56SzRu5QEnJoT//YK1IMUd0v3 wt89MpXfh3p1l8s Df0XLc4FoTMaD1SoQzwrVEc4z4uoyrrXFfPjtexfCwgrPdQlzgOUCJcBYH2ANO0WTtC3H4mX PzpnDiKQxJEXNpIb0HeVgzGnSZ1ybEAqbF7kHkym1oiXl8Pm5w n7hn1UljxUxLa8 cChLY02y6Wizqk/p2m GKubN4 HlxvpOSBDGghv5Elsmov4r/r9Lrj/NQJzNO2TK5asJ/XokCyYicy 8W0NMmzmmpCa9eXzHntVPyiu5dUrV/Y7ZjZWy0gNdNZs67dLsK8/mR/fQEgmn4kYCpuCPR1H4t/Yw9g9s6ZW tvWZKkz5ydtldeaVduo WhCkKrH1AfLQIXeX1sq9WWkfxCtmfqL2Y4621d1ZRZd0nstpykR5Zxy5CrhFAEBRvYuDgVZiVhFEJVPNI/CX9qJzwjDPQjkfcr/bA6fjCCeBRNR92DhwF6qr Jg3qTcVskwubvOiIgZb7zSl0Qdql IrNjDCDz552eIUub3Y/9SLLGQSdweaNtB7BgnCR1J6EKCU33ZgLWmv wvRobejwdJFQZaztBnkjMzxXW/nUEjhJ5V8nYDfrzGVDPWybkKVvKOuWk5QtpHYDIeIxYBzauOeip0IpaaHzkoyOKy5PcLWsCkjLI93poyghoBRGtSIC3GnJBNBVkhTgHG5cAIVsnM6hynp AGu cU1Yd8NmUOmizgjCW98LZcnY05fIvYrDCMEtSheJkShipjZD1tSWocShqs5fqWz Ri7wP31bwEjopI DoMAujoNropdhvoZbGDVQON8riiDFFPqw8hAmtqsXvNFFfWqKy73LDL2R7CBBUKfPhDSpuPU2OXwjI4V/cLB /fvsyPS2AgQ V4bzCz6s6Ys8 ERCZ3BJS6fI7RsTim JZs7vhUlUTG6V5ztEh/qSmC37iuRoT0FENzrHwp3rDXjRSx0NPONGrLgffsDd9NLz0t/2c8PfwBvi1SP0xr6p5 kdR10XiIhRkcizCn12SzwQXW/agTebzlZid4MZl2NVF92PeJTSp6fFtzGxYQNVswuDn/jMOPG7vHoCTtYsd5FpNNTIlWWcazH9dqwBdHOk36TJl20Dnkn320dAabHorXTMAD1ZjtxJ n44GX4egpFtiJgIgL0hPBLJn7cNVAVhDXtwtAdGivbxz7BE9Q1kYxxq2Y XOphcQUO7DJDHVJ/ftcymjjOfwhw/JYvCiV6ehmZa26kcwsaPuImET7T2oiwQJE1MVyC1tjACEimX1dG6aaTVSrriUp kWl1hToI4LDO7lX/lpC0gnZbil6gpTC6wvbQtgke08/ge7amm4YRAArU4FvTw2hBTBQBWe9dAzYsE /tvoMgOJFVoFIR91B5jY T1hjL8iUunWwZP3FL33cZ/cxjWe3wOeQMPBxplnCZWnfsoI96w aNR7RWmQVHNqrKheUPuDhRpe4NORn53fsgDHY6JPaopTm88Y/6QHvszBwi4ojsF/Ffnn0FWdj8Zknf5z gPqR6HflCEzHGhq6sWZHfpZi6m8n/7PEdGyNQJW2W3uvDnvXdcg76OPbrye7churwRR v2w9V0Ba4cv2V6v3KHU/6dFldoHTNNEhYyXL48TCPzmdZNF6pRyQ7MLkyW/e H7ArDMrP kqVrGPGWVZfjsM/9QCx1Y7uM7Myizhpb3 GHlxjAsbm10fVA/42H1WvuMinD6gljGtH2sXdLeEYpjz9ICC1YejDq8XVe2Km h7RbQrYI5spa11/OhcuJcSDs5xKjZX6vEjZfqO2jBHYnDSusqJ7l0t2Yit8xeGvBAnMNcTkPwzDb511cLysCczKnTc6At4ImBfWjq8koYOgFJgTkEttqo6d9KvALJZLPEqqFcb3BfBXvV993sSeBWErWbybSfLWpMa7JW/t0KlXbdJrZMSjEio2cpNvWfqws3qDvpYOVhDyQtlc7U/FfExaEI3uZYkw5hs2b5oCuSKqkN3Vw4aucRRPIZKPBAUlV4WwzOp7b  sFEd6uKTe6YSS4NbeqI6X6uijJj1jYPYnvDKrihkUEgc4l2mMv1laElniCyV jTYLD7BPnCdyaRX2YYzLuJr/Q5O503ipJgc br09dVyelUPQ3dW2U2LpeioC7q0I3vac2zbQKFf1e0kQtVNZl6YIQCJ9kPZTkEsKAR2xBQcjjorciaqqgR0urveGwCxogRzMhwhKAml2iYsdhm0t/c3TxWwsJXAbpBJOrybffndsJl8koc4SIb/ZGxf0xWafYrxNshK8Yj3CtYQC6qAMowrvqp34KPMSsR t4vrgZ1MejuV7/xA2TITCLemqtqbcrhjawhbWKwrPDaju4r1lSdWIobQK4px72LNkogNI tJlm P3hXt1qD7UQMPNVlcP 5QQIZUto8awKcBmF1DbcPGnKPklGVn9peSJEce4iMFnjxPlyFtD0QmE0TqvAxIcSWlg1J9ju/WP71 zVQ5doztO9fgjchs6lbtKgSm8m7WvXbiTyvMQOFAIPm8HXnzIHEc97j3TsA0hSD5/IpczmjA4vP2fagCGRagU7th8SSXrR3H7V6voknjmqksM2o2sXAxv0VzPTUxv2W/cFq4 66evmwGN2qsaEoShNTdowO0 q82/aaIX1W5kmQs=
Referer : 
Path : /
IsConnected : True
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : 
HResult : -2146233088
Stack Trace : The stack trace is unavailable.
Additional Info:

MachineName : MMMS
TimeStamp : 12/5/2017 5:39:21 PM
FullName : Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities, Version=10.1.6500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563
AppDomainName : /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131569168130850096
ThreadIdentity : Anonymous
WindowsIdentity : IIS APPPOOL\censored
Requested URL : https://www.censored.com/?50068%253ouggcf%253n%252s%252sjjj.zzsbbqznexrg.pbz%253n44314%252sra%252s50056%253s5005725%25354bhttps%25393a%25292f%25218fwww.censored.com%25344a4439981%25245fen%25254f5009067%25361f500384782%2537019ouggcf%253259n%2521967s%2521157sjjj.zzsbbqznexrg.pbz%2537244n443235015%252423sra%252552s500208163%2532898s500192822%253562475bhttps%253624917a%25278822f%252685664fwww.censored.com%253142937a4439096575%252792339fen%2525862f5003417492%253165211f5008369103790%25366309365ouggcf%25385327175n%25237864073s%2524182246sjjj.zzsbbqznexrg.pbz%2538330215n4434840246535%2524160299sra%25259573238s5003694994068%253067725s500356623876972%2535494869753bhttps%2532945234039a%252936931228f%252488634540fwww.censored.com%2531061775413a44365974325475%252181498645fen%2522543689526f50070531877612%2532041912112f5004523326119420%253662674351510ouggcf%25392275222940n%252363622589989s%252971120749323sjjj.zzsbbqznexrg.pbz%25353434715289n44396162915945459%252906964251395sra%25218371186722s50022482691717858%2528437264826f%2521201469s%252295558f%2527142s%25243f%252s/
    Inner Exception
    ---------------
    Type : System.FormatException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    Message : Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
    Source : mscorlib
    Help link : 
    Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
    TargetSite : Int32 FromBase64_Decode(Char*, Int32, Byte*, Int32)
    HResult : -2146233033
    Stack Trace :    at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
       at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
       at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
       at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose)
       at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.EnsureEventValidationFieldLoaded()



Category: ErrorLog

Priority: 0

EventId: 90000

Severity: Error

Title:Enterprise Library Exception Handling

Machine: MMMS

App Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131569168130850096

ProcessId: 10176

Process Name: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Thread Name: 

Win32 ThreadId:9012

Extended Properties: 
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Probably somebody is just probing your site for vulnerabilities. 
I would execute the same URL as those guys did and see what kind of exceptions are thrown and whether any private info is leaked.

Comment: Just tried that - it just displays the home page. Today the exceptions are completely different so I think you're right.